# Specialization of a generic-generic parameter with another, simple-generic parameter

Tags: scala

I'm currently working on a project that includes Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning. Considering the examples and explanations in the [book](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf), I'm trying to create a generic function for the various parameters that are part of a trained GP-object - thus, the following declaration is the most general one for a (simple) training function.

```
def train[T, M <: MatrixInverter[T], S <: Kernel[T]](): GP_Spawn[T] = null
```

(I've removed the parameter list and the implementation, just if you're wondering.)
`T`describes the numeric type, e.g. it may be `Double` or `Int`. `MatrixInverter[T]` is a trait that enforces a `calculateInverse` function. `Kernel[T]` is the corresponding trait for a kernel-function.
As some of you may already know, training in a gaussian process can be changed (somehow simplified) when using a *Cholesky-Decomposition* as the matrix-inverter - thus, I've considered to specialize the function mentioned above. Due to the documentation of the `@specialized` tag, it should be something like this:

```
def train[T, @specialized(CholeskyDecomposition[T]) M <: MatrixInverter[T], S <: Kernel[T]](): GP_Spawn[T]
```

It's obvious that all parameters are more or less depending on `T`, since they need to use some variables (types `T`,`Vector[T]`,`Matrix[T]`) that depend on it. If I try to compile the code mentioned above, the scala-compiler (2.9.2) complains about

> error: not found: value CholeskyDecomposition

I'm not sure what this means, since the import `import algorithms.{CholeskyDecomposition, MatrixInverter}` is correct. Besides, it's curious to see that the import of `CholeskyDecomposition` is marked as *Unused import statement*. `CholeskyDecomposition` has a companion that includes some constants that are related to the algorithm itself, but I don't assume this aspect to be the reason for this error.

Any ideas what may cause this error ? And, furthermore, how to solve it **without** cutting of the generic approach ?

**Edit:**

After reading the answers are considering some re-ordering of my code, I ended up with a solution at runtime that uses type-matching.

```
val testMat = new Matrix[T](3, 3)
val testInv = fac(testMat)    
testInv match {
    case chol : CholeskyDecomposition[T] => println("Found Cholesky!")
    case _ => println("Found something different.")
}
```

And it works now :) Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/specialized.html), it says:

```
Type T can be specialized on a subset of the primitive types by
specifying a list of primitive types to specialize at:
```

So it is basically only for primitive types.

Answer (score 5):

You can only specialize a generic parameter with a primitive type: `Int`, `Double`, etc. So you can specialize `T` but not `Foo[T]` even if `T` is a primitive.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a class `C` that is specialized on type `T`, then

```
class D[@specialized T, C[T]](c: C[T]) { ... }
```

will use the `T`-specialized verson of `C`.

This is all you need anyway.  There is no point to specialization on object; generic code works just as well since everything non-primitive is an object anyway.

Comment: I don't want to specialize on a primitive, e.g. instead of `CholeskyDecomposition[T]`, `SingularValueDecomposition[T]` is a valid option - but both remain depending on `T`. I cannot cut this of without dramatically changing the whole concept.

Comment: @DorianGrey - What you say is orthogonal to my point.  If you are not confusing generics (and possibly higher-kinded types) with specialization, you need to be more clear about what it is you think that specialization will buy you in this case.

Comment: Hm... it would require a deeper knowledge about Gaussian Processes to understand that completely. But I suppose the only important thing to understand the problem I've been facing is that the implementation changes in several ways if a Cholesky Decomposition is used for matrix inversion, since some other characteristics come along with it that can be used to speed up the calculation. I thought it would be useful to automize implementation-selection based on specialization, avoiding runtime overhead. As I've mentioned in the edit, it was possible to solve it using type-matching.